# Android parse array attr in custom widget for custom NumberPicker

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm create new Custom widget for NumberPicker and i want to fill items by array in array.xml for this action i'm create new define in array.xml:

```
<integer-array name="Items">
    <item>1393</item>
    <item>1394</item>
    <item>1395</item>
    <item>1396</item>
    <item>1397</item>
</integer-array>
```

application attr is :

```
<declare-styleable name="CNumberPicker">
    <attr name="maxValue"               format="reference" />
    <attr name="minValue"               format="string" />
    <attr name="value"                  format="string" />
    <attr name="displayedValues"        format="string" />
    <attr name="focusable"              format="boolean" />
    <attr name="focusableInTouchMode"   format="boolean" />
</declare-styleable>
```

define xustom widget in layout xml:

```
<com.sample.widget.CNumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/np_choose_year"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="0.20"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
    app:maxValue="@array/Items"
    app:minValue="0">
</com.sample.widget.CNumberPicker>
```

now in custom widget class i must be parse an array with `setMaxValue` for NumberPicker as an:

```
public class CNumberPicker extends net.simonvt.numberpicker.NumberPicker implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

private String maxValue;
private String minValue;
private String value;
public CNumberPicker(Context context) {
    super(context);
    //LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_schedule_date_time, this);
}
public CNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(attrs);
}
public CNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(attrs);
}
private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CNumberPicker);
    final int id = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CNumberPicker_maxValue, 0);
    /*final int[] values;
    if (id != 0) {
        values = getResources().getIntArray(id);
    }
    setMaxValue(Collections.max(Arrays.asList(values)));*/
    setMaxValue(Integer.parseInt(a.getString(R.styleable.CNumberPicker_maxValue)));
    setMinValue(Integer.parseInt(a.getString(R.styleable.CNumberPicker_minValue)));
    setValue(Integer.parseInt(a.getString(R.styleable.CNumberPicker_value)));
    a.recycle();
}


@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    setValue(19);
}
```

}

`‍setMaxValue` only accept int and could not parse Array, how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Array has multiple values so why are you assigning it as the max value?

Answer (score 0):

Redefine `Items` as a string array.

```
<string-array name="Items">
    <item>1393</item>
    <item>1394</item>
    <item>1395</item>
    <item>1396</item>
    <item>1397</item>
</string-array>
```

and change your code as

```
final String[] values;
if (id != 0) {
    values = getResources().getStringArray(id);
    setDisplayedValues(values);
}
```

Comment: get this error : `The method setMaxValue(int) in the type NumberPicker is not applicable for the arguments (int[])`for  setMaxValue  and  `Bound mismatch: The generic method max(Collection<? extends T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<int[]>). The inferred type int[] is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>>` for max

Comment: Fixed and tested as well. Use the Arrays class instead.

Comment: i get this error : `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '@2131623938' as integer`

Comment: i think i must be use `setDisplayedValues` instead of `setMaxValue` is this correct?

Comment: Do you want to display one single max value or all the values?

Comment: set all values in array to numberPicker

Comment: Then yes, use `setDisplayedValues()` but it'll take a string array. So, modify your code as shown in my update.

Comment: thanks sir. in number picker i have only fist item of defined array and i can not change it to other array values

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? It's unclear what you're saying. Update the question with more details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71148/discussion-between-tuxworld-and-ravi-thapliyal).

Comment: i can not switch in all variables into array items and i have only one item in number picker for example i can not choose 1394 or 1395 numberPicker only have one item